# React Native "this.setState is not a function"

Tags: javascript, binding, react-native

I'm starting with react native and trying to bind some actions to class methods but I'm getting some errors about methods not found.

I tried binding:

```
class AccountsScreen extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.userChange = this.userChange.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
      <Text>Pass</Text>
      <TextInput
          onChange={this.userChange}
      />
      </View>
    )
  }
  userChange (user) {
    this.setState({user: user})
  }
}
```

and arrow functions

```
class AccountsScreen extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
      <Text>Pass</Text>
      <TextInput
          onChange={(user) => this.userChange(user)}
      />
      </View>
    )
  }
  userChange (user) {
    this.setState({user: user})
  }
}
```

but I keep getting the same error:

> "this.setState is not a function"

Totally stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: this.userChange = this.userChange.bind(this) you still need to bind i guess, take a look at difference between two constructors

Comment: Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

actually no need to make a function to set your state, you can just do this

`<TextInput onChangeText={(user) => this.setState({user: user})} />`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a stupid mistake. I was using onChange instead of onChangeText method....

Comment: Then we can close the question or you can delete it.